# MySQL Join Multiple (More than 2) Tables with Conditions

Tags: mysql, join

Assume I have 4 tables:

Table 1:  `Task`

```
ID     Task            Schedule
1      Cut Grass         Mon
2      Sweep Floor       Fri
3      Wash Dishes       Fri
```

Table 2:  `Assigned`

```
ID     TaskID (FK)     PersonID (FK)
1          1                1
2          1                2
3          2                3
4          3                2
```

Table 3:  `Person`

```
ID     Name
1      Tom
2      Dick
3      Harry
```

Table 4:  `Mobile`

```
ID     PersonID (FK)     CountryCode     MobileNumber
1          1                 1           555-555-5555
2          2                44           555-555-1234
3          3                81           555-555-5678
4          3                81           555-555-0000
```

I'm trying to display the

1. Task on a certain day
2. Name of person assigned to task
3. Phone numbers of said person

I think it should be something like the following, but I'm not sure how to set up the conditions so that the results are limited correctly:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.Task, P.Name, M.MobileNumber
FROM Task AS T
LEFT JOIN Assigned AS A
     ON T.ID = A.TaskID
LEFT JOIN Person AS P
     ON A.PersonID = P.ID
LEFT JOIN Mobile AS M
     ON M.PersonID = P.ID
WHERE T.Schedule = Fri
```

My goal is to fetch the following information (it will be displayed differently):

```
Tasks                        Name             MobileNumber
Sweep Floor, Wash Dishes     Dick, Harry      44-555-555-1234, 81-555-555-5678, 81-555-555-0000
```

Of course, if JOIN is the wrong way to do this, please say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you want to do with duplicate data in this case, but you should be looking at using inner joins instead of outer joins, and using something like group_concat() to combine the phone numbers.

Comment: Why inner joins vs outer joins?  If there were no one assigned to a task at the moment, wouldn't that mean that I would get no results?

Comment: Then you need an outer join on the Task-Assign joining. You also probably need an outer join on the Person-Mobile join (to catch persons without mobiles). But for Assign-Person, an inner join is enough (unless `Assign.PersonID` field is nullable.)

Comment: @ypercube Thanks, but I ended up using all outer joins because of the nullable fields.  Also, if anyone is interested, I ended up using `IFNULL()` with the `GROUP_CONCAT` part.  Also, Bryan Alves, thanks for the suggestion to use `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: @user928984: OK. `GROUP_CONCAT()` is very useful for these things. You can also define the order of the concatenated values and the separator between them: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Also check the `COALESCE()` function that is more general than `IFNULL()` and available in other RDBMS too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: @ypercube I couldn't get `COALESCE()` to work with `GROUP_CONCAT()` because it still results in the occasional `NULL` which `GROUP_CONCAT()` won't display. I'm using `GROUP_CONCAT()` on a list of items, so if one has a `NULL`, they all won't display. With `IFNULL()`, I just have it display a space. Thanks for your help, though. I'm sure I'll use `COALESCE()` in a different situation.